# (export LC_ALL=C; xxd -revert -plain <<< 1234abcd | rev | tr -d '\n' | xxd -plain | tr -d '\n') not work why?

Tags: ubuntu

```
(export LC_ALL=C; xxd -revert -plain <<< 1234abcd | rev | tr -d '\n' | xxd -plain | tr -d '\n')
rev: stdin: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

its most return cdab3412

but return

```
rev: stdin: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 1234abcd | grep -o .. | tac | paste -sd '' -

cdab3412
```

Answer (score 0):

If the system's `rev` is not able to handle the byte sequences as character, perhaps try perl:

```
$ (export LC_ALL=C; xxd -revert -plain <<< 1234abcd | perl -pe '$_ = reverse $_' | xxd -plain)
cdab3412
```

I omitted the newline removals - they don't seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using `rev` and `sed`:

```
$ rev <<< 1234abcd | sed -E 's/(.)(.)/\2\1/g'
cdab3412
```

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F '' '{ for(i=NF-1;i>0;i-=2) printf "%s", $i $(i+1) } END{ print "" }' <<< 1234abcd
cdab3412
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `rev` with the following one-liner:

```
perl -nle 'print scalar reverse $_'
```

<sup>Source: [Perl one-liners](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/7328094)</sup>

At least it won't break on invalid encodings.

For easier use, create the following alias:

```
alias reverse="perl -nle 'print scalar reverse \$_'"
```